# Form partial not rendering rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't get any error messages when I load the page the only issue is the the comments form isn't rendering in the browser.

```
<div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-12 blog-content">
<h2 class="text-center"><%= @post.title %></h2>
<h5 class="text-center"><%= @post.created_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y') %></h5>
<div><%= raw @post.body %></div>
<br>
<h2><%= @post.comments.count %></h2>
<%= render @post.comments %>
<h3>Add a comment...</h3>
<%= render partial: 'comments/form'%>
</div>
```

Here is the comments form I am trying to render.

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :body%><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body%>
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is name of your comments form and what's the full path?

Comment: the name is _form.html.erb and the path is views/comments/_form.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

The comments partial form should exist in this full path **app/views/comments/_form.html.erb**. Then this should work

Comment: Yeah that's the path the partial is in.